# raise_not_found_error configuration to false not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am playing around with rails and mongodb and running into the issue where find_by returns an error when it does not find a result. I have already triple checked to make sure it's under options and not session/options.

Can anyone help? thanks
already checked to make sure it's set under options, not session options

Error

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:
Problem:
  Document not found for class VinDecode with attributes {:numOfDoors=>"3"}.
Summary:
  When calling VinDecode.find_by with a hash of attributes, all attributes provided must match a document in the database or this error will be raised.
Resolution:
  Search for attributes that are in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error.
```

Below is my mongoid.yml

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:

  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have two issues:

1) You need to un-indent your options

2) You should move your options below your test declaration

I ran into this same issue where it was working for my production code, but not working in my test environment and the solution was because the options were defined before the test declaration.

If you are planning on writing tests for your code which I highly recommend, you should move your options like below

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0

options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```